# Liferay - Where menu is genereated

Tags: liferay, controls, panel

I am using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

When You go to Control Panel -> Site Settings, You have menu on right side.

My question is - Where this menu is generated? I need to hide something from there ("Staging" and whole SEO section). I spend day and so on it and couldn't find proper spot.

Comment: When asking the same question in multiple locations (e.g. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/40694488), please indicate so on both ends next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay's portal.properties contains this section:

```
#
# Input a list of sections that will be included as part of the layout form
# when updating a layout.
#
layout.form.update=details,seo,look-and-feel,layout,javascript,custom-fields,advanced,mobile-rule-groups
```

Also, as you're speaking about site update:

```
#
# Input a list of sections that will be included as part of the form when
# updating a site.
#
sites.form.update.main=details,categorization,site-url,site-template
sites.form.update.seo=sitemap,robots
sites.form.update.advanced=default-user-associations,staging,analytics,content-sharing,recycle-bin
sites.form.update.miscellaneous=custom-fields
```

Take a look at those places in portal.properties, then override what you need to change in portal-ext.properties, restart Liferay and check if you picked the right setting.

Comment: It's all I wanted. I can add from myself, that if You still have section You don't want to it means that it's added in portal.properties in other hook.

Comment: from a hook you can only *add* entries to the end of those comma-separated lists, not remove. You'll need to change your portal-ext.properties file (e.g. in ${liferay.home}) or have an ext plugin (but that would be overkill for this purpose IMHO)